# copy file in 8.3 format produces "There is already a file with the same name in this location" error in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-transfer, xcopy

I use xcopy and batch scripting to backup newer files `xcopy "src" "dest" /O /X /E /H /K /I /D`. I was asked if I want to replace something which should not happen. So I did the copy process manually and found the following

[image]

[Filename not equal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8f0L.png)

How can these two filenames be equal?

Comment: *[Sensitive](https://www.google.ca/search?q=define:sensitive) information, not [Sensible](https://www.google.ca/search?q=define:sensible). ;)

Comment: Thanks man! The German translation is "sensible Informationen" and yet no one before corrected me... but probably made fun about me ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADVANC~2(2).PDF is a **long filename** (no 8.3 notation). It is the copy of the 8.3 notated file ADVANC~2.PDF and became this way a file with a long name.

What is its 8.3 name?

use:

> dir /x ADVANC~2 (2).PDF

The 8.3 name will be most likely `ADVANC~4.PDF`

These are the limitations of the 8.3 / long filename mix.